# Create a session for a page input and submit at final page

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I have a 4 pages
page 1 has a form with inputs
page 2 has no form, but redirects
page 3 has a form with inputs
page 4 has a form with inputs.

**Edited** - (Added code)

```
Page 1
<form action="page2" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="sex">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

Page 2
    <?php require_once 'detect.php'; ?>
    <input type="text" name="size">
    <input type="hidden" name="sex" value="<?php echo $_POST['sex'] ?>" >
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
    <!--
    setTimeout("location.href = 'page4';",5000);
     -->
    </script>

Page 3
<form action="page4" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="colors">
    <input type="hidden" name="sex" value="<?php echo $_POST['sex'] ?>" >
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

Page 4
<form action="verNote.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="likes">
    <input type="hidden" name="sex" value="<?php echo $_POST['sex'] ?>" >
    <input type="hidden" name="colors" value="<?php echo $_POST['colors'] ?>" >    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I am thinking of using session() as it would be the most convenient way to handle this, to collect and post inputs of all pages to the final php handler which in this case is "verNote.php".

I would also appreciate if i can get a practical solution to this.

Thanks.

Comment: Surely (not Shirley), you can Google this. There's a whole bunch of examples out there.

Comment: I think you should NOT use cookies for that, because cookies are user-editable. Depends on what informations you need to carry, I would still go for SESSION solution. You sure know how to put stuff into session, and if you don't, you should google it.

Comment: What's the problem with hidden inputs? I use them all the time to hide data to send to the next page. If you really can't use them, do as Eda190 said: session object.

Comment: Any practical application so i can understand pls? I have googled and applied it all, but sill dont work for me, maybe im doing something wrong.

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- try this, here is no need of **middle.php**

**page1.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if ( isset( $_POST[ "anything" ] ) ){ 
  $_SESSION[ "anything" ] = $_POST[ "anything" ]; // by this value from the form are stored in $_SESSION[ "anything" ]
  header( "Location: page2.php" );
}

else header( "Location: page1.php" );

?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Session</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Welcome to page 1.
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <form method="post" action="page1.php">
      Type anything
      <input type="text" name="anything" />
      <input type="submit" value="Send value to page 2" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**page2.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Session</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Welcome to page 2.
    <br/>
    <br/>
    This is the value from page 1 :
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['anything'];?>" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In every php page write the first line

```
session_start(); // this must be the first line of every page in php
```

then after this, create session variable as follows:

```
$_SESSION['sex']=<variable_name_to_store> ;
```

Later in each page where you want to access this session variable value, use directly **$_SESSION['sex']**.
Like `<?php echo $_POST['sex'] ?>`

Comment: so, if page1.php posts to page2.php,
Page2.php should have something like:

<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['sex']= "selectedsex";
include('detect.php'); 
?>

    <input type="text" name="size">
    <input type="hidden" name="sex" value="<?php echo $_POST['sex'] ?>" >
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
    <!--
    setTimeout("location.href = 'page4';",5000);
     -->
    </script>

Correct?

Comment: Something like that, Ruse Yee, but not exactly and not that easy. To store the value in Session you require a middle script between page 1 and page 2: page 1 sends the value from a form input, the middle script stores it in Session, then page 2 can get the value from Session.

Comment: yes like that.. but there is a mistake in "include('detect.php');"  it must be "include 'detect.php'; " and it is not posting data to any other page. by this you are JUST creating a session and that is created in browser. browser store that data. simply it means that you are storing data in browser somewhere through page1.php and accessing that data from any other page through session variables. i.e. $_SESSION['sex'];

Comment: and do not forgot to write first statement as session_start(); in every php page in which you want to access that data.

Comment: and in middle.php the syntax for "isset( $_POST[ "anything" ])" will be this. Not "IsSet( $_POST[ "anything" ] )"

Answer (score 0):

With Session, you don't need to store the same value in every form of every page (like you are doing with "sex"). With Session, you store the value once and it stays there. Now an example.

For page 1 to send data to page 2, it is needed a middle script to take the value from the input form and store it in Session. Next code is an example.

**page1.php** (sends value to page 2).

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Session</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Welcome to page 1.
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <form method="post" action="middle.php">
      Type anything
      <input type="text" name="anything" />
      <input type="submit" value="Send value to page 2" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**middle.php** (takes the value from page 1 and stores it in session)

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( IsSet( $_POST[ "anything" ] ) )
     { $_SESSION[ "anything" ] = $_POST[ "anything" ];
       header( "Location: page2.php" );
     }
else header( "Location: page1.php" );
?>
```

**page2.php** (displays the value received from page 1)

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Session</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Welcome to page 2.
    <br/>
    <br/>
    This is the value from page 1 :
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["anything"];?>" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Ruse Yee, create 3 textfiles and name them page1.php, middle.php and page2.php, copy-paste the appropiate code in them and run page1.php from your browser:

http://localhost/page1.php

You can add the port if necessary :

http://localhost:80/page1.php

If you have more pages with forms sending more data, then you will need more middle.php files.

Hope this helps you.